# Gauss-Jordan Elimination Last Row Complications

Tags: c, matrix

currently I am trying to find the inverse of a given matrix through gauss-jordan elimination on the augmented matrix such as:

```
4
10
3.000000,1.000000,1180.000000,1955.000000,221900.000000
3.000000,2.250000,2570.000000,1951.000000,538000.000000
2.000000,1.000000,770.000000,1933.000000,180000.000000
4.000000,3.000000,1960.000000,1965.000000,604000.000000
3.000000,2.000000,1680.000000,1987.000000,510000.000000
4.000000,4.500000,5420.000000,2001.000000,1230000.000000
3.000000,2.250000,1715.000000,1995.000000,257500.000000
3.000000,1.500000,1060.000000,1963.000000,291850.000000
3.000000,1.000000,1780.000000,1960.000000,229500.000000
3.000000,2.500000,1890.000000,2003.000000,323000.000000
```

The first integer is the number of columns in X, the second integer is the number of rows, and a column of 1s is added in front of these elements.  The last column of the matrix makes up matrix Y.  This is the algorithm that I had created to find W = (XT * X)^-1 * XT * Y, with w = weight, XT = the transpose of X, and ^-1 representing finding the inverse of the product.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        if(argc < 2){
                printf("error.");
                return 0;
        }
        FILE *fptrain = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        //FILE *fptest = fopen(argv[2], "r");
        if(fptrain == NULL)
        {
                printf("error.");
                return 0;
        }
        int row, col, i, j;
        fscanf(fptrain, "%d", &col);
        col = col+1;
        fscanf(fptrain, "%d", &row);
        char ch;

        //creates the original X and Y matrix
        float trainX[row][col];
        float trainY[row][1];
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                trainX[i][0] = 1.000000;
                for(j=1; j<col; j++)
                {
                        fscanf(fptrain, "%f%c", &trainX[i][j], &ch);
                }

                        fscanf(fptrain, "%f%c", &trainY[i][0], &ch);
        }

        //multiplies X and X transposed
        double trainXtemp[row][row];
        int s;
        double num=0;
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<row; j++)
                {
                        for(s=0; s<col; s++)
                        {
                                num = num + trainX[i][s]*trainXtrans[s][j];
                        }
                                trainXtemp[i][j] = num;
                                num =0;
                }
        }

        //finds the identity matrix of X times X transposed
        double trainXinden[row][row*2];
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<row; j++)
                {
                        trainXinden[i][j] = trainXtemp[i][j];
                }
                for(j=row; j<row*2; j++)
                {
                        if(j==i+row)
                        {
                                trainXinden[i][j] = 1.000000;
                        }
                        else{
                                trainXinden[i][j] = 0.000000;
                        }
                }
        }
 //finds the inverse of X times X transposed through Gauss Jordan Elimination
        int k;
        double divscalar;
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                divscalar = trainXinden[i][i];
                for(j=0; j<row*2; j++)
                {
                        if(trainXinden[i][j] != 0)
                        {
                                trainXinden[i][j] = trainXinden[i][j]/divscalar;
                        }
                }
 for(k=0; k<row; k++)
                {
                        if(i!=k)
                        {
                                double subscalar = trainXinden[k][i];
                                for(j=0; j<row*2; j++)
                                {
                                        trainXinden[k][j] = trainXinden[k][j] - subscalar*trainXinden[i][j];
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
 //copies over the result of gauss jordan elimination
        double trainXinverse[row][row];
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<row; j++)
                {
                        trainXinverse[i][j] = trainXinden[i][j+row];
                }
        }
  //multiplies (X times X transpose) inverse by (X transposed)
        double trainXinvXt[col][row];
        for(i=0; i<col; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<row; j++)
                {
                        for(s=0; s<row; s++)
                        {
                                trainXinvXt[i][j] += trainXtrans[i][s]*trainXinverse[s][j];
                        }
                }
        }
//multiples (trainXinvXt) by Y
        double weight[row][1];
        for(i=0; i<col; i++)
        {
                for(s=0; s<col; s++)
                {
                        weight[i][0] += trainXinvXt[i][s]*trainY[s][0];
                }

        }
return 0;
}
```

This calculates the inverse values correctly, except for complications in the last column's few rows, on the final loop, the inverse matrix is calculated incorrectly because of this.  What is the best approach to fixing this? [the operation must be performed on an augmented matrix and rows cannot be exchanged]

Comment: This is not enough for someone to try out your code. Please give a *complete* minimal example, that someone can simply cut and paste to try to reproduce your trouble.

Comment: Your approach will run into trouble if at any step the diagonal element `trainXinden[i][i]` is very small or zero.  You'll get better numeric stability if at each step you exchange rows so as to put the element having maximum absolute value on the diagonal.

Comment: @AhmedMasud I have edited to include the full code

Comment: @MMar `trainXtrans` not defined so not "full code".